# how to convert empty parameters to null when struts2 accept parameters

Tags: parameters, struts2, null, string

I am using struts2 data model to accept request parameters,  if user does not type any value in input element, the corresponding property in model class is set to "", but I want it to be null, not "".
here is my code:

```
class User{
    private String userName;
    private String userId;

    //setter & getter omitted
}

class UserAction extends ActionSupport{
      private User user;
      //setter & getter omitted

 }
```

in `UserAction` class, I maybe need do some business validation or something else, I just use statements lik `if(user.getUserId() !== null)`, now this condition returns true even if user doesn't type anything in `<input type="text" name="user.userId" />`. 
maybe I can write like this:`if(user.getUserId() != null && !"".equals(user.getUserId()))`, it is a little tiring and there are many places like this in my code, I want a convenient way to achieve this, does filter can do this? if can is there any exsiting filter or interceptor ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not choosing a more abstract, object oriented, framework-independent way to do this ?

```
class User{
    private String userName;
    private String userId;
    //setter & getter omitted

    public boolean isEmpty() {
       return (userId==null || "".equals(userId));
    }
}
```

---

```
/* somewhere in your Java code: */
if (!user.isEmpty()) {
```

---

```
<!-- somewhere in your JSP code: -->    
<s:if test="!user.empty()" >
```

Alternatively you could alter the `getter`s to return `null` even if the value is `empty String`, (or vice versa) but usually this forcing is not good.